# ColladaLoader2.js - random colors are overwriting .dae file settings (three.js)

Tags: three.js, blender, collada

I'm working with Three.js (r73) -- based on a bug in ColladaLoader.js, I transitioned to ColladaLoader2.js. However, when I load a .dae file with ColladaLoader2.js, instead of taking the color defined in the .dae file, it applies a random color. The colors of the object randomly change every time I refresh the page. Also, i noticed that shadows from lights no longer apply.

Here are two examples to illustrate this issue. The ONLY difference between these two examples is that one uses ColladaLoader.js and the other uses ColladaLoader2.js. Everything else is the same.

Ex 1 - ColladaLoader.js - the .dae file loads in and shows as expected (same as what it looks like in Blender, which is where the .dae file was exported from)
http://ngndev.com/share/three/cl.html

Ex 2 - ColladaLoader.js - notice the color and lack of shading? It's the same .dae file. Try refreshing the page. The color will change every time to some random color. 
http://ngndev.com/share/three/cl-2.html

Has anyone experienced this or have a solution?

Here's an excerpt from the example showing how I'm adding the .dae. I'm essentially opening the .dae, traversing and then adding it to the scene if it matches by name.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

//Load in the part
loader.load('e3d-ppppp7.dae', function (collada){
    voxel = collada.scene;
    voxel.traverse(function (child){
        if (child.name.match("^e3d-")) {
            scene.add( child );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `ColladaLoader2` is under development. Try the updated version in the r.74dev branch. If you find a bug, then you can report the bug on the three.js site.

Comment: Thank you @WestLangley - I was directed to the updated ColladaLoader2.js file and this solved the issue. Unfortunately, my "up" axis is now thrown off (as you'll see if you refresh example #2 above). I tried adding and removing "loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;" but this didn't solve the issue.

Comment: As a work-around, try rotating the geometry in the loader callback. `mesh.geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 )`.

Comment: I implemented this work-around and it worked successfully. In case it is useful to anyone else - I am importing a myriad of "THREE.Group" and "THREE.Mesh" objects so I had to tweak the work-around to apply to both cases ("geometry" is further nested in the "Group" situation). Thanks for the speedy responses @WestLangley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ColladaLoader2` is under developement to replace `ColladaLoader`. Try the three.js development version (r.74dev in this case.)

If you find a bug in the new loader, it would be helpful if you report it. See the three.js [guidelines](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for how to report a bug.

three.js r.73